# How to Export Java Project in Eclipse with Image Library as a jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I want to export my java project as a jar file, with the images on it.

I followed these instructions :http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm

But after I try to run my jar file it gives `"Invalid or corrupt jarfile"` error.

What is more when I export as a runnable jar file, icons that I added to my code are not shown. How should I import them in jar file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to export with Runnable Jar file this time [image]

to answer your second query choose the followin option

[image]

Comment: I also selected that option but it has still without icons.

After I click finish, it says "finished with warnings". Does it make a problem ?

Comment: you need to check the location of your image file ... put them in the classes folder and then they should be included

Answer (score 0):

Try to export as a runnable jar.

Comment: When I export as a runnable jar file, icons that I added to my code are not shown. How should I import them in jar file ?

Answer (score 0):

Salaam,
Please try using ant to build your jar (depends is optional)

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="myapp.jar"
         basedir="."
         includes="**/*.*"
         />
  </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...jar file, with the images on it.

Do you want to change the icon of the JAR ? If yes the short answer is, you cant do this by including an image.
But you can try [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) ! It simply creates an exe-File for your jar.